# Busqueda y llenado de formulario en c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

estoy intentando hacer un tipo de buscador de matricula y que si esa matricula existe me mande a un formulario con mis datos llenos, pero no se me ocurre como hacer el llenado del formulario, ¿Alguna ayuda? Me recomendaron eval pero la verdad no entendi como usarlo

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: y que has intentado? con el resultado de tu busqueda deberias crear un objeto y pasarlo a tu siguiente formulario y asignarlo a tus componentes para mostrar.